# React and Firebase - Query based on object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query data from Firebase based on object value. I want to get only the child which key matches to `mainGoal` value.

**Data is structured like so:**
[image]

**And this is how I am trying to query the data:**

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    let mainGoalKey = dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid+'/mainGoal');

    mainGoalKey.on('value', snap => {
        this.setState({
          mainGoalKeyState: snap.val(),
        });
    });

    if (this.state.mainGoalKeyState) {
      const dataGoalRef = dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid+'/'+this.state.mainGoalKeyState);
      dataGoalRef.on('value', snap => {
          this.setState({
            dataGoal: snap.val(),
          });
      });
    }
  }
```

> Edit: I want to get object values under the key that matches the
>   mainGoal value. So something like:
>    `const dataGoalRef =
>   dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid).orderByValue().equalTo('mainGoal');`

**Is there any way to do so?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use orderByChild to match the desired data.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    let mainGoalKey = dbRef.child('goals').orderByChild(mainGoal).equalTo(this.state.uid);

    mainGoalKey.on('value', snap => {
        this.setState({
          mainGoalKeyState: snap.val(),
        });
    });

    if (this.state.mainGoalKeyState) {
      const dataGoalRef = dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid+'/'+this.state.mainGoalKeyState);
      dataGoalRef.on('value', snap => {
          this.setState({
            dataGoal: snap.val(),
          });
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. What I want to do is reference to firebase database as `dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid+'/'+this.state.mainGoalKeyState)` where `mainGoalKeyState` is set from the first value snap. I don't either know if I can do multiple snapshots at the same time.